# Выравнивание текста в Item-ах ListBox-а

Tags: c#, wpf

Добавляю массив строк в ListBox так:

```
SearchPath.ItemsSource = obj.ReadDefaultSearchPaths();
```

Как этот текст выравнивать? Я знаю как выравнивать сами Item-ы, а как текст внутри них не знаю.

Comment: А как вы хотите выравнивать? Покажите, какого эффекта вы хотите добиться.

Comment: И какого типа ваши элементы списка?

Comment: Если выравнивать Item-ы то текст будет перемещаться, но внутри Item-a сам текст будет, например снизу, а мне нужно сверху.

Answer (score 1):

Например:

```
        <ListBox Name="SearchPath">
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel FlowDirection="RightToLeft"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    </ListBox>

        public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        List<string> list = new List<string>
        {
            "shrt itm",
            "middle item",
            "l o n g   i t e m",
            "vsi",
            "v e r y   l o n g   i t e m"
        };
        SearchPath.ItemsSource = list;
    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Как вы сделали, чтобы высота Item-а была в размер строки? Мне нужно тоже самое, но ваш код не позволяет этого сделать.

Answer (score -1):

Понял в чём дело. Я читал строки из файла. Поэтому в них была куча всяких \n, \r и пробелов. Проблему решил)